# Radeon R9 280X 4K Flickering issue

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, resolution, radeon

I am running a XFX Radeon R9 280X with a Samsung U28D590D monitor. Using HDMI for 4K @ 30Hz works well, but when I switch to using the mini-dp port to get 4K @ 60Hz I get ridiculous flickering! It starts with the splash screen and continues. If you drop the resolution the flickering goes away. Booting the same rig into windows displays 4k @ 60Hz without any issues. I have tried the open source drivers, the 14.6 beta drivers and the latest omega drivers without any luck. I have reached out to AMD Tech Support but no response as yet. Can anybody suggest anything else to try?

Comment: You have tried almost everything that can be done. This can probably be only resolved by AMD.

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue, but with built-in 4k display on my Dell Inspiron 7548 using an R7 M250.

Comment: Exact same setup - flickering only happens with chrome, so far...